# C# Algorithm Time Complexity

Tags: c#, algorithm, time-complexity

I have this code and I am trying to work out the time complexity of it when n=2, n=4 and n=6. Can anyone help me? I'm confused as how I do it? Big-O Notation please.

```
using System;

class TimeComplexityTest
{
    public static void Main( string[] args)
    {
        int n;

        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the value of n");
        n = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); 
        Console.Write("\n");

        for (int i = 1; i <= 1.5*n; i++)
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        for (int i = n; i >= 1; i--)
            Console.WriteLine(i);

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Comment: miissing some curly brackets? the time complexity shouldnt change with n surely?

Comment: What exactly do you want - the algorithm complexity in big-O notation or just time in milliseconds for your piece of code?

Comment: o(n) surely? but shouldn't the loops be nested?

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking O(N), but I'm just a learner and wasn't sure... Thanks.

Comment: Note that "the time complexity for n = 2, 4, 6..." does not really make sense: Time complexity describes the dependency of the run time as a function of `n` so it is not really relevant what it looks like for particular values of `n` - what _is_ relevant is how is _scales_ -- e.g. if `n` doubles, does the run time stay approximately the same, does it double, or even quadruple, for instance. This is what the Big O-notation expresses.

Comment: @CompuChip Thanks, that really helped actually. I have no idea what I'm doing haha.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 2 loops: one running 1.5n times, and the other running 1n times.
The time complexity for that is 2.5n, which is O(n).